# Python Script Tool with validation not opening in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool, tool-validation

I am trying to figure out why my ArcGIS Pro Python Script Tool with validation fails to open when I insert the block of code in my image.

```
def initializeParameters(self):
    shpFile = r"C:\LPA\Data\ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp"
    self.params[0].filter.list = sorted([row[0] for row in
arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shpFile, "NAME")])
      return
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think that it is the two extra spaces of indentation before your first `return` that is causing the problem.

Try this instead of the code that you have presented:

```
def initializeParameters(self):
    shpFile = r"C:\LPA\Data\ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp"
    self.params[0].filter.list = sorted([row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shpFile, "NAME")])
    return
```

In a comment you showed a misspelt line of code that was giving a different error:

```
self.params[0].filter.list = sorted( [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursur(shpFile, "NAME")])
```

should have `SearchCursor` (not SearchCursur):

```
self.params[0].filter.list = sorted( [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursur(shpFile, "NAME")])
```